# sqlldr : ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: sql-loader, ctl

i want to import csv file. my script is :

```
@echo off
set numid=2015092510524361378197540100
sqlldr USER@db/PSW data=csv\2015092510524361378197540100.csv control=ctl\control.ctl log=log\2015092510524361378197540100.log bad=bad\id.bad
pause
```

my table is :

```
CREATE TABLE SV (NO1 VARCHAR2(255),NAMA VARCHAR2(255),ALAMAT VARCHAR2(255),id VARCHAR2(20),JAB VARCHAR2(50),numid VARCHAR(55));
```

my control.ctl is :

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=43, errors=12000) LOAD DATA  APPEND INTO TABLE sv when NAMA <> '' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' optionally enclosed by '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS (no filler,no1 "TRIM (:no1)",nama "TRIM (:nama)", alamat "TRIM (:alamat)",id "TRIM (:id)",jab "TRIM (:jab)",numid "%numid%")
```

error is :

```
Record 10: Rejected - Error on table sV, column numid.
ORA-00911: invalid character
```

please let me know which one is wrong. thanks All

Comment: You left out the csv file itself. Specifically record 10.  The numid column. Actually I don't know what the percent signs are for around numid in the control file, but the numid inside of them should have a colon in front.

Answer (score 1):

Since numid is a VARCHAR2(55), change the table datatype to be VARCHAR2 and the control file to read:

```
numid "TRIM(:numid)"
```